# LINQ to XML - Querying Elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

> 

```
 <Contents>
   <Content Book="ABC">
      <Item type="New" id="1" File="book1.out"/>
      <Item type="Old" id="2" File="book1.out"/>
   </Content
</Contents>
```

> 

In the above XML I need to get the string  "Book1.out" as output
there where condition is Book="ABC" and ID ="1"

How to do this in LINQ in one shot, without iterating the results.

This my initial code :

```
var result = (from query in _configDoc.Descendants("Contents").Descendants("Content")
              where query.Attribute("Book").Value == "ABC") select query;
```

Thanks..

Comment: and what does your initial code produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of the the Item element with attribute book = "ABC" and id = 1:

```
var result = _configDoc.Descendants("Content")
   .Where(c => c.Attribute("Book").Value == "ABC")
   .Descendants("Item").Single(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "1").Value;
```

This is the straightforward version without null-checking on the attributes. Also, depending on your real-world scenario, an XPath expression could be simpler.

Comment: Hi Driis, Book == "ABC" is in a different node and id is in a different node  <Contents> 
   <Content Book="ABC">

Answer (score 0):

You could skip LINQ and use XPath instead, like this:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

...
var result = _configDoc.XPathEvaluate("/Contents/Content[@Book='ABC']/Item[@ID='1']/@File");
```

Comment: Hi Lawrence, thank you for your reply. To maintain the consistency I had to use LINQ in my code.